# If $\phi$ $is$ harmonic in V then show that$\int\int_{S}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial n}dS=0$ where S is surface enclosing V

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> **Question**If $\phi$   $is$ harmonic in V then show that$\int\int_{S}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial n}dS=0$
>   where S is surface enclosing V

**MY Problem** This is a solved problem in my book but i can't understand
it on the following points

1.What is $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial n}$? What is $\partial n$?

I know $\hat{n}$is unit normal to the surface.

2.In the solution $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial n}$$\mathbf{n}$=
$\nabla\phi$This is used.

There is no formula given in the book related to this concept.I can't
understand this formula.How is this possible?

**Edit** I am going add a picture of the solution,to make it more clear[image]

Comment: As I've typically seen it, $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n}$ is a shorthand notation for the change in $\phi$ as it moves normal to the surface $S$. They then vectorize this to make it into a gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_{S}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial n}dS=\int_{S} {\nabla \phi \cdot \boldsymbol{n}}   dS=\int_{V} {\nabla \cdot\nabla \phi }   d\tau =\int_{V} {\nabla^2 \phi }   d\tau=\int_{V} {0}   d\tau=0$ by the divergence theorem since $\phi$ is harmonic.

Comment: $\int_{S}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial n}dS=\int_{S}{\nabla\phi\cdot\boldsymbol{n}}dS$
Please explain this

Comment: This did not address the questions that the OP asked.

Comment: $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial n}$ is the notation defined by $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial n}=\nabla\phi \cdot n$

Comment: What is $\partial n$? is $\partial n$
 anywhere related to normal unit vector ?

Comment: Yes, it means the directional derivative of $\phi$ along the normal vector $n$ of the surface $S$.

Comment: @Chriskim I am not doubting your formula,but books seems to have taken extra-steps of taking $\mathbf{n.n}$ and then it used associative property,as infinityLord said about it

Answer (score 1):

By divergence formula we have 
\begin{align*}
\int_{V}\text{div}(W)dx=\int_{S}W\cdot n_{x}dS(x), 
\end{align*}
put $W=\nabla\phi=\left(\dfrac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_{1}},...,\dfrac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_{n}}\right)$, then $\dfrac{\partial\phi}{\partial n}=\nabla\phi\cdot n_{x}$, and $\text{div}(W)=\dfrac{\partial^{2}\phi}{\partial x_{1}^{2}}+\cdots+\dfrac{\partial^{2}\phi}{\partial x_{n}^{2}}=0$.

Comment: $\dfrac{\partial\phi}{\partial n}$ means the directional derivative of $\phi$ at $x$ with normal $n_{x}$.